# How to build a minimax position tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tree, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

For a Connect4 game I need to convert this AlphaBeta algorithm to the AlphaBetaWithMemory algorithm explained by Aske Plaat in his MTD(f) algorithm: https://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/mtdf.html#abmem

Therefore, I need some hints on how I can build a minimax tree board position of the possible moves to be able to loop through its child nodes in the same way as AlphaBetaWithMemory.

I really hope you guys can give me some advices, please.

Thank you.

```
Game.prototype.alphabeta = function( board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer ) {

    // Call score of our board
    var score = board.score();

    // Break
    if (board.isFinished(depth, score)) return [null, score];

    if( maximizingPlayer )
    {
        // Column, Score
        var max = [null, -99999];

        // POSSIBLE MOVES
        for (var column = 0; column < that.columns; column++) 
        {
            var new_board = board.copy(); // Create new board

            if (new_board.place(column)) {

                that.iterations++; // Debug

                var next_move = that.alphabeta( new_board, depth-1, alpha, beta, false ); // Recursive calling

                // Evaluate new move
                if (max[0] == null || next_move[1] > max[1]) {
                    max[0] = column;
                    max[1] = next_move[1];
                    alpha = next_move[1];
                }

                if (alpha >= beta) return max;
            }
        }

        return max; 
    }
    else
    {
        // Column, score
        var min = [null, 99999];

        // POSSIBLE MOVES
        for (var column = 0; column < that.columns; column++) {
            var new_board = board.copy();

            if (new_board.place(column)) {

                that.iterations++;

                var next_move = that.alphabeta(new_board, depth-1, alpha, beta, true );

                if (min[0] == null || next_move[1] < min[1]) {
                    min[0] = column;
                    min[1] = next_move[1];
                    beta = next_move[1];
                }

                if (alpha >= beta) return min;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [AlphaBetaWithMemory](https://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/mtdf.html#abmem) algorithm is a standard alpha beta algorithm which uses a [Transposition Table](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table).

So, if your alpha beta algorithm works, you only have to add a transposition table to store information from previous searches. Without a transposition table, MTD(f) will still to be correct but not very efficient.